# How to use a variable in filename

Tags: python

I am trying to use the current date & time as a file name for my spreadsheet file but I keep on getting the error "no such file or directory exists."
Below is the code that I tried to use:

```
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M.xlsx")
wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Comment: try changing it to `saveAs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your file name:

```
time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y_%H:%M.xlsx")
```

When this statement is executed it returns a result like this:

```
'10/06/2015_11:44.xlsx'
```

Do you have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
/PathToScript
   /10
      /06
          2015_11:44.xlsx
```

Those `/`s in the file name are indicating directories. If you wish to have a D-M-Y pattern, I suggest using something other than a `/` as a separator:

```
time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M.xlsx")
```

Comment: also a note about saving in a date format @Aldwin.. its better to keep the format yyyy-mm-dd as your files will be sorted incorrectly when looking at it as a date (files are sorted numerically)